# What's eyebuild?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

I would like to know what's eyebuild because tonight I found this message in the google chome dev console

> eyeBuild: initialize() called eyeBuild: is now live

However, I don't have this message with edge.

My website is working with wordpress and I didn't change the code in the last few weeks.

Comment: did you install or update a plugin? https://specs.eyereturn.com/eyebuildhtml.html

Comment: no, not lately.